# Hyva Themes : Magento2 How To Create Sticky Header?

Tags: magento2, hyva, alpine.js, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

I'm looking for a code that can help me with sticky header for hyva themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my working code example.
It's also eliminated jerking of sticky header!!

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {
        showDesktopMenu()
    };

    function showDesktopMenu() {
        let header = document.querySelector('#header'); //main header div
        let navbar = document.querySelector('.desktop-navbar'); // child div of main header div
        let body = document.querySelector('body'); // document body
        if (window.pageYOffset > header.getBoundingClientRect().height) {
            navbar.classList.add('sticky-custom');
            body.style['padding-top'] = navbar.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px";
        } else {
            body.style['padding-top'] = "0px";
            navbar.classList.remove('sticky-custom');
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    .sticky-custom {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is on [hyva](/questions/tagged/hyva), you can use `TailwindCSS` classes on the `<header>` tag.

Add the following classes: `sticky top-0 z-10`.

The `z-10` can be increased/decreased based on your page since it only brings the block forward to avoid having another block covering the header.

This can be done by extending the template file `Magento_Theme::layout/default.phtml`:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container" htmlClass="page-header sticky top-0 z-10"/>
</body>
```